# "Knowledge of" vs. "Knowledgeable in"

Tags: grammar, expression-choice

How would I phrase this in a job description?  Would I use "knowledge of" or "knowledgeable in"?

> Knowledge of navigating through large databases.

Comment: It's "navigation", not "navigating".

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Corpus English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+knowledge+of%2C+have+knowledge+in%2C+*+knowledgable+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20knowledge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20knowledge%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbe%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmore%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvery%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmost%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0):

I ***have*** knowledge ***of*** navigating through large databases.

I ***have*** knowledge ***in*** navigating through large databases.

OR

I ***am*** knowledgeable ***in*** navigating through large databases.

[Knowledge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knowledge) is one thing:

> 2. Familiarity, awareness, or understanding gained through experience or
>      study:
>
> I have **knowledge** of navigating through large databases.

[Experience](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/experience) is another:

> 2.a. Active participation in events or activities, leading to the accumulation of knowledge or skill:
>
> 2.b. The knowledge or skill so derived.
>
> I have **experience** in navigating through large databases.

[Expertise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expertise) still another:

> 1. special skill, knowledge, or judgment; expertness
>
> I have **expertise** in navigating through large databases.

Answer (score 5):

Whichever way you choose, you should remain consistent throughout your document. I am assuming this is going to be presented as part of a bulleted list. Each item in the bulleted list should be a continuation of the same sentence fragment. For example, each of these bullet points run off the fragment: "*I have the*":

> - Knowledge of navigating through large databases
> - Ability to brew excellent coffee
> - Milkshakes that bring all the boys to the yard

Each of these bullet points run off the fragment: "*I am*":

> - Knowledgeable in navigating through large databases
> - Skilled at brewing excellent coffee
> - Capable of having milkshakes that bring all the boys to the yard

The choice is yours; just ensure that all your bullet points continue the same fragment.

Comment: This is a good answer, but putting the base fragment **after** the examples is confusing. Better to say, "For example, each of these bullet points run off the fragment *I have the*:..." Then, "Each of these bullet points run off the fragment: *I am*:... goes before the second list.

Comment: I suppose it is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for a clearer, yet still formal sentence you could try

> Knowledgeable in the navigation of large databases.

or even

> Knowledgeable in the navigation of vast amounts of information in large databases.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Skilled at" or "Capable of"? If you prefer a sentence, "With my experience at Whatever Company, I know how to navigate through large databases."

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>  "knowledge of navigating through large databases"- is correct.
> ```
>
> Also consider-
>
> - In-depth knowledge of navigation through large databases
> - extensive knowledge of navigating through large databases